# How do I select and calculate the data from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of facture and a table of fournisseur, but I want to select all my fournisseur from the database and I want to calculate the field nvsolde (solde-SUM(facture.montant)). But when I use this request it gives just fournisseur already had a facture.

```
SELECT fournisseur.id
     , fournisseur.nom
     , fournisseur.solde
     , fournisseur.solde-SUM(facture.montant) AS nvsolde 
FROM fournisseur
   , facture 
WHERE facture.id = fournisseur.id 
GROUP BY fournisseur.nom"
```

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: yeah, i have lot of facture has the same fournisseur , i use group by to help me when i calcul the nvsolde of the fournisseur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way you describe the problem, you need a `left join`.  This is a good time to add this advice:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

```
SELECT fo.id, fo.nom, fo.solde,
       fo.solde - COALESCE(SUM(fa.montant), 0) AS nvsolde 
FROM fournisseur fo LEFT JOIN
     facture fa
     ON fa.id = fo.id 
GROUP BY fo.id;
```

Some notes:

- You need the `COALESCE()` in case there are no matches.  This converts the `NULL` to `0`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The `ORDER BY` uses the `id` column, which is presumably unique in `fornisseurs`.  The use of a primary key or unique key in the `GROUP BY` is acceptable and a good practice (even consistent with the ANSI standard).  However, using other columns is definitely a *bad* practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help